# How to fit models to data?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

I am working on a project in which I am comparing how well and exponential, logistic and Gompertz model fit to tumour growth data. I have the equations for all three models but I don't know how to go about fitting the models to the data? Is there software (that's relatively simple) I can use or can I also do it manually?

I would prefer doing it manually but I have no way of accurately defining the parameters needed to fit to the data (like growth rate, carrying capacity etc.), which makes me think software is easier.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: R has pretty nice libraries to do this.

Comment: As Don Thousand mentioned, R has libraries to do this. You can do it in Python as well. Excel's not bad, actually. You can set up your error as the sum of least squares, and use the Excel Solver routine to manipulate the parameters to minimize the error.